# How to create the header of a CSV file?

Tags: python, file, csv, header, writer

i want to write a csv file in Python. I want to use these 2 words as header.

```
import csv


myFile = open('tabelle.csv','w')

with myFile:
    writer = csv.writer(myFile)

 writer.writerow(["Wort","Haeufigkeit"])
```

Is that enough to build my header? Now I want to add in this csv file the other words under this two words. Does python now accept this as a header or just as a normal row?

Comment: Have you seen csv.DictWriter? Its "writeheader" method is exactly what you're looking for: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as the csv writer is concerned the header is like any other row. The idea of a header comes up only when you want to read and interpret a csv file. So, what you said does work.

Comment: Nit-pick: What the OP has won't work because the `writer.writerow(["Wort","Haeufigkeit"])` isn't indented properly under the `with`—so it raises an `IndentationError`.